# Knockout JS Disable dropdown option after selecting it and re enabling it after clicking a button X

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I want to create a dropdown with three options

```
var viewModel = {

    items: ko.observableArray(['one', 'two', 'three'])
};
```

If I click on one, the currently selected item 'one' will be disabled, and will only be enabled in the dropdown if I click on a button. Can someone please help me with code sample and logic. Please the sample code should only by in knockout JS no jquery or javascript please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be better if you had shown what you've attempted.

There are different ways to do it. Here is an approach using knockout:

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/kyr6w2x3/43/   
**HTML :**

```
<select data-bind="foreach: items, value: selectedOption">
  <option data-bind="value: value, text:name, attr: {'disabled' :IsDisable}" ></option>
</select>
<input type="button" data-bind="click: btnClicked" value ="Click To enable one">
```

**JS Model :**

```
  function YourViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    var options = [ {name: 'One', value: '1'},
                    {name: 'two', value:'2'},
                    {name: 'three', value:'3'}
                   ];
    self.items = ko.observableArray();
    self.selectedOption = ko.observable();

    $.map(options, function (item) {
       self.items.push(new drowpDownOptionViewModel(item));
    });
    // subscribe to selected option 
    self.selectedOption.subscribe(function (newValue) {
        // if One is selected make it disable
        if (newValue === 1){
           ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.items(), function (item) {
              return item.IsDisable(item.value() === 1);
          });
        }
    }, self);

    self.btnClicked = function (){
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.items(), function (item) {
         item.IsDisable(false);
     });
    }
  }
 function drowpDownOptionViewModel (data){
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable(data.name);
    self.value = ko.observable(data.value);
    self.IsDisable = ko.observable(false);
 }


ko.applyBindings(new YourViewModel());
```

**Another example based on comment** :https://jsfiddle.net/kyr6w2x3/44/

Comment: Matt I want to modify the code so If I click on 'one' it's is disable like it's now and if I click on two "One and Two" are  disabled and so with the third one. But as soon as I clicked on a dropdown option a button will be made for that option and clicking on that button will only enable that option. The enable button will not be visible unless I click on any option and that button will be hide when I enable that option. Please note that I can enable disable any options 1,2 or 3 or all of the three so button count will be equal to the options count. Matt please help I am new to knock out

Comment: Here is the link what I need, I wanted to create this example in pure knockout way.

http://jsfiddle.net/pd5Nk/1/

Comment: Here is the link for what you explained. https://jsfiddle.net/kyr6w2x3/44/